# Return array of order of items in drag-sort-listview android

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview

I am making an android app that ranks items .  I have populated the drag-sort-listview, however after the user re ranks the items, how do I return the new order in an array?

Does it have to do something with a cursor such as [this](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview/blob/master/library/src/com/mobeta/android/dslv/DragSortCursorAdapter.java)?

EDIT:

How would I implement this method so when I click a button it logs out the array of positions?  Also I am using the default demo scripts of [drag sort listview](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) which uses a fragment for the listview.  I am new to android, so I think I understand the pieces I need, just not how/where to do them (in MyActivity.java or the dslvframent.java)

MyActivity.java

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            DSLVFragment f =
                    (DSLVFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG_DSLV_FRAGMENT);


            DragSortListView dslv = (DragSortListView) f.getListView();

            List<Integer> newOrder = dslv.getCursorPositions();

            String positions = Arrays.toString(newOrder);
        });
```

DSLVFragment.java

```
...
protected void setListAdapter() {

String[] ranking = {"item1","item2","item3"}

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(ranking));
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), getItemLayout(), R.id.text, list);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
...
```

Does all the code need to be in MyActivity.java or does dslvfragment.java need some?  Basically I am asking for a simple example on how to use getCursorPositions() in the context of the Bauer demo.  I've websearched for examples, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call getCursorPositions to get a list of the original positions of the items in the list. So if you list starts as:

> a, b, c, d, e

and you change the positions to

> b, d, a, e, c

getCursorPositions will return

> [1,3,0,4,2]

You can also use getListPosition(int cursorPosition) to get the new position of the item at cursorPosition. In the previous example, getListPosition(2) (where 2 corresponds to "c") will return 4, as "c" is in position 4 in the reordered list.

getCursorPosition will do the opposite of getListPosition. It will get the original position of an item in the reordered list. So getCursorPosition(4) will return 2.

Comment: This is the answer, however I am not competent enough to implement it, see my edit for more.  But much thanks the pointing of the right direction.

Comment: If you use a fragment then you should put all the logic in the fragment class. In the onclicklistener onclick method just put List<Integer> newOrder = mDragSortListview.getCursorPositions(). Then String positions = Arrays.toString(newOrder)

Comment: Infact none of the DragSortCursorAdapter class methods cannot be resolved.  Do I have to pass the Class into my mainActivity?

Comment: I used an ArrayList adapter to populate my listview.  Do I need to use the DragSortCursorAdapter instead?